# JavaScript Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, user-interface

I'm interested in creating a web interface where a user can break up a "timeline" into various chunks.

```
Start|-----------------------------|End
         ^marker one   ^marker two
```

They would be able to add a marker (and label it), and then move the marker around adjusting its position.

All the sliders I've looked at so far only support one slider between a range of values

Is there any existing jQuery plugins or any other javascript libraries (or even HTML5 /SVG ) that have a good starting point for this feature already?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're talking about something akin to a slider with multiple handles, rather than a timeline as such. The SIMILE timeline is probably the best out there, but it doesn't allow for dynamic [band creation](http://code.google.com/p/simile-widgets/wiki/Timeline_BandClass) as far as I know, so I think sliders are your best bet. Here's a jQuery UI slider demo, with two "handles":

[jQuery UI range slider demo](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0571__jQuery/jQueryUISliderRangeslider.htm)